# Import a persistent key in to Windows key storage using CNG storage functions

Tags: c++, key, blob, cng

I'm trying to import a persistent RSA public key into the key storage. I read on the [CNG help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427412(v=vs.85).aspx) that it's possible for private keys and I wonder if I can also apply is to public keys (specifically the BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB). I've tried with the following code, but in the import section, when I call NCryptSetProperty to set the public blob as a property, I get "Error 0x80090029" which is NTE Bad Data. Having trouble debugging why this function is failing.

```
NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE providerHandle = NULL;
NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE keyHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
PBYTE blob = NULL;
DWORD blob_len = 0;

///////////////////Export Test (extract key from storage)///////////////////////////

// Open handle to the Key Storage Provider
if(FAILED(status = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
    &providerHandle,            //OUT: provider handle
    MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER,    //IN: Microsoft key storage provider
    0)))                        //IN: dwFlags (unused)
{
    //report fail
}

// Open key in the Key Storage Provider
if (FAILED(status = NCryptOpenKey(
    providerHandle,
    &keyHandle,
    keyName.c_str(),
    0,
    0)))
{
    //report fail
}

// (2 step key extraction process) 1. Get size of key
if (FAILED(status = NCryptExportKey(
    keyHandle,              //IN: Handle of the key to export
    NULL,                   //IN(opt): key used to encrypt exported BLOB data   <-- potentially an safer way for key extraction, encrypt it with a key during extraction (decrypt with NCryptDecrypt)
    BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB,  //IN: BLOB type (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
    NULL,                   //IN(opt): List of paramters for the key
    NULL,                   //OUT(opt): Output byte buffer
    0,                      //IN:  Size of the output buffer
    &blob_len,              //OUT: Amount of bytes copied to the output buffer
    0)))                    //IN: Flag to modify function behaviour (0 means no flag set)
{
    //report fail
}

// Allocate data blob to store key in
blob = (PBYTE)malloc(blob_len); 
if (NULL == blob) {
    //report fail
}

// (2 step key extraction process) 2. Get key and store in byte array (Extracted key is in form of BCRYPT_RSAKEY_BLOB)
if (FAILED(status = NCryptExportKey(
    keyHandle,
    NULL,
    BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB,
    NULL,
    blob,
    blob_len,
    &blob_len,
    0)))
{
    //report fail
}


///////////////Import Test (Store into storage)//////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a persisted key
if(FAILED(status = NCryptCreatePersistedKey(
    providerHandle,             //IN: provider handle
    &keyHandle,                 //OUT: Handle to key
    NCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,       //IN: CNG Algorithm Identifiers. NCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM creates public key
    keyName.c_str(),            //IN: Key name. If NULL, the key does not persist 
    0,                          //IN: Key type
    NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG)))//IN: Behaviour: 0 - apply to current user only, NCRYPT_MACHINE_KEY_FLAG - apply to local comp only, NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG - overwrite existing key
{
    //report fail
}

// Set the size of the key
if(FAILED(status = NCryptSetProperty(
    keyHandle,                          //IN: Handle to key
    BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB,              //IN: CNG Algorithm Identifiers. BCRYPT_RSAPUBLIC_BLOB allows me to use set this blob as the new key's blob
    blob,                               //IN: Key name. If NULL, the key does not persist 
    blob_len,                           //IN: Key Length
    0)))                                //IN: Bahaviour: 0 - apply to current user only, NCRYPT_MACHINE_KEY_FLAG - apply to local comp only, NCRYPT_OVERWRITE_KEY_FLAG - overwrite existing key
{
    //report fail <<-------------------------- Fail here
}

// Finalize key generation (Key is now usable, but uneditable) 
if(FAILED(status = NCryptFinalizeKey(keyHandle, 0)))            {
    //report fail
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I'm kind of disappointed in myself for not reading more, but I saw a blurb that says: 
> "For BCryptExportKey to create a persisted key pair, the input key BLOB must contain a private key. Public keys are not persisted."
This means I shouldn't be able to create persistent key just as a public blob.

Answer (score 2):

On creation of an asymmetric key, one of the properties that can be set is the NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY. I used this to control whether the private could be read or not.

```
//... after NCryptCreatePersistedKey()

    DWORD export_policy = NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG | NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;

    if(FAILED(status = NCryptSetProperty(
        keyHandle,
        NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY,
        (PBYTE)&export_policy,  
        static_cast<DWORD>(sizeof(DWORD)),
        NCRYPT_PERSIST_FLAG | NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG)))
    {
        //report error
    }

//... before NCryptFinalizeKey()
```

The properties are defined here. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376242(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to import a full RSA key using this method but when I'm calling NCryptSetProperty to set NCRYPT_EXPORT_POLICY_PROPERTY, the call fails with NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED